# Implicit real error

Tags: fortran

I have written program with `implicit real*8`. The program is working fine but as soon as i inserted another data file that contains the data of long and double precision digits than the results i found were not appropriate. Experts and the program developers adviced me to change `implicit real*16`. But it is not working in my fortran power station 4.0 and giving implicit error. How to convert or upgrade the power station so that it can work with `implicit real*16` or more?

Comment: Retagged to Fortran, since I don't think this has anything to do with Java. Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: No 'expert' advised you to use 'implicit real*'.

Answer (score 2):

Powerstation is too old. Not every compiler supports real*16 even now. Consider to obtain a new compiler. I suggest to begin with gfortran, that does support quad precision for sure.

Also I am worried that with that implicit things there might be many other problems hidden. Consider also explicit typing for your variables and using `implicit none`.

Answer (score 2):

What are the values in your file?   integers and double precision floating point values?  Then it seems very unlikely that the problem is caused by your not reading them into quad-precision real variables.  Only rarely do calculations need quad-precision.  Are you reading the integer values into integer variables and the floats into Fortran reals?   As the others have written, implicit typing is the worst approach ... it is still part of Fortran only to support legacy code.  Best practice is to use "implicit none" and explicitly type all of your variables.  This will allow the compiler to catch mistakes such as typos in variable names.   For more about variable typing see [Fortran: integer*4 vs integer(4) vs integer(kind=4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4/3170438) and [Extended double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211037/extended-double-precision/9215930)