# Fortran handling large real numbers with precision

Tags: fortran, precision

When I run the code below I get an output of 6378136**.5** instead of 6378136**.3**

```
PROGRAM test

implicit none
real*8 radius

radius = 6378136.3

print*,radius

END
```

I have read this other link ([Precision problems of real numbers in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016261/precision-problems-of-real-numbers-in-fortran)) but it doesn't explain how to fix this problem.

Comment: The most exact duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146005/is-there-a-better-double-precision-assignment-in-fortran-90/6150181

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is not because the variable you are using lacks precision, but because you initialized the value using a single precision number.

Take a look at [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-to-set-double-precision-values-in-fortran) for a good explanation, and an elegant solution to your problem for any larger programs.

If you just want to solve it quickly, then you only have to change one line:

```
radius = 6378136.3d0
```

Though this will still give you a value of `6378136.2999999998` because of floating point precision.

Comment: Also at https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/IoI5Mes2Se4